# Unity UniWebView how to show images from my Resources (Assets)

Tags: unity-game-engine, uiimageasset, uniwebview

i have a few quick questions:
background:

- i want to display a in-code generated html with UniWebView in my game. Mostly works nicely until i try to display local images (from my unity-resources)
- the images are in my "Resources" folder (and used elsewhere in the project also)
- my goal to support Android/iOS/Windows environments with the game

Q1: can i display images from "Resources"? this would be the best if i could
Q2: do i need to move all my assets into the "StreamingAssets" folder and access from there? if so, can "StreamingAssets" folder be under "Resources" folder? like this: "Resources/StreamingAssets"? If so please confirm that i can use them as unity resource for unity components AND also streamable assets for UniWebView in the same time?

thanks!

daniel

Comment: You might want to check these docs:
https://docs.uniwebview.com/guide/loading-local-files.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @sammonius: thanks! i know that, i look for (in Q1) a possibility without streamingassets folder (if any). OR in Q2 if i can make the streaming assets folder inside REsources folder.

TO cummunity_bot: there is Q1 and Q2 are the questions.